# Will Allah (S.W.T) forgive me for this sin?

Tags: shirk, tawba

I committed shirk and then after sometime I asked repentance from Allah (S.W.T). So will Allah (S.W.T) forgive me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you repented and changed your ways, not only will Allah forgive you He will change this sin into a good deed:

Those who invoke not, with Allah, any other god, nor slay such life as Allah has made sacred, except for just cause, not commit fornication― and any that does this (not only) meets punishment (25:68) (But) the Penalty on the Day of Judgment will be doubled to him, and he will dwell therein in ignominy― (25:69) Unless he repents, believes, and works righteous deeds, for Allah will change the evil of such persons into good and Allah is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful (25:70).